# React: How to create different size input fields using antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I've tried as below and all the fields appear the same:

```
<Input size="large" placeholder="Username" prefix={<UserOutlined />}/> <br/><br/>
<Input placeholder="default size" /> <br/><br/>
<Input size="large" placeholder="Password"/> <br/><br/>
<Input size="small" placeholder="Small size"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if you imported css from Ant Design?

I've read the official documentation and it says to

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

What are your investigations so far?

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code since it looks similar to sample code that they have provided.

https://ant.design/components/input/